# Average of a column "combined_lead_score"

Tags: sql

```
l_i.title AS title,
l_i.industry AS industry,
CAST(l_i.combined_lead_score as varchar(10)) AS combined_lead_score,
CAST(AVG(l_i.combined_lead_score) as varchar(10)) AS avg_combined_lead_score,
```

Full Code

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT
      l_i.lead_name AS name,
      l_i.lead_source AS lead_source,
      l_i.lead_source_detail AS lead_source_detail,
      l_i.campaign_source_name AS campaign_source,
      l_i.title AS title,
      l_i.industry AS industry,
      CAST(l_i.combined_lead_score as varchar(10)) AS combined_lead_score,
      CAST(AVG(l_i.combined_lead_score) as varchar(10)) AS avg_combined_lead_score,
      l_i.created_date AS date,
      'Inbound' AS category,
      l_i.lead_id AS id,
      COUNT(l_i.lead_id)
   FROM {{ref('leads')}} l_i
   WHERE l_i.lead_status != 'Unqualified' AND l_i.lead_source_type IN ('Events', 'Inbound')
```

How do I see the average for combined_lead_score, what I have done now just throws the same number for both

Comment: Your code sample has no `union` so your question is quite unclear.

Comment: Simplify! Show us some sample table data _and the expected result_ - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

AVG is an aggregate operation, but you're not aggregating, just selecting distinct rows. what you want is a GROUP BY.

I don't know the exact shape/state of your data, but assuming you want the *total* for `combined_lead_score` for all entries which have the same `lead_name`, `lead_source`, `lead_source_detail`, etc, and also the mean average and count for the same...

You probably want something more like this:

```
SELECT 
  l_i.lead_name AS name,
  l_i.lead_source AS lead_source,
  l_i.lead_source_detail AS lead_source_detail,
  l_i.campaign_source_name AS campaign_source,
  l_i.title AS title,
  l_i.industry AS industry,

  /* fetch TOTAL for lead score as 'combined'*/
  CAST(SUM(l_i.combined_lead_score) as varchar(10)) AS combined_lead_score,

  /* fetch AVG for lead score as average */
  CAST(AVG(l_i.combined_lead_score) as varchar(10)) AS avg_combined_lead_score,
  l_i.created_date AS date,
  'Inbound' AS category,
  l_i.lead_id AS id,
   COUNT(l_i.lead_id)
FROM 
  {{ref('leads')}} l_i
WHERE 
  l_i.lead_status != 'Unqualified' 
  AND l_i.lead_source_type IN ('Events', 'Inbound')

GROUP BY
  l_i.lead_name,
  l_i.lead_source,
  l_i.lead_source_detail,
  l_i.campaign_source_name,
  l_i.title,
  l_i.industry,  
  l_i.created_date,
```

Comment: I changed it and still get the same output, I had a GROUP BY, but didnt enter it here my bad

Comment: Well what are you actually looking to achieve?  It's hard without some idea of what the data is like - are there multiple rows per lead?  are there likely to be multiple rows for any one lead on any one date?  speaking of date, is created_date a **date** or actually a timestamp? if a timestamp then since that's in the list of `group by` fields it'll probably  only ever include one row in each aggregate row (is that `COUNT` column always `1`?)